# How do you get all matches in a repeated backreference?

Tags: php, regex

With the test string:

```
This is a string1 string2 string3 string4 string5 string6 string7 so it is.
```

Is it possible to get all the stringXs as backreferences? Currently what I've tried ends up overwriting each time so I end up with one match - the last one.

For instance using a regex like this:

```
/This is a (?:(string\d) )+so it is./
```

Would always end up with a match of `string7` at the end.

The best I've found so far is to remove the `?:` above and explode on the spaces, but I'd be interested in whether there's a way to do it purely with regex.

**update** specifically to PHP, what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: It cannot be done with "regex", since any regex is used in *code*. What is yours? Note that getting all *captures* is only available in few languages.

Comment: The minimal example is using preg_match with the caluss above in PHP but I didn’t want to limit it to a language. I guess I could have specified PCRE, but I’m really just asking about regex.

Comment: What's the flavor/environment?

Comment: @Aran-Fey ahh you’re right I’ve been looking to find a similar answer but was failing. I should probably delete this that answers it nicely.

Comment: Actually I’ve updated specifically to PHP

Comment: No need to delete - you can mark your own question as a duplicate of that. Your question can serve as a signpost for other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex using `\G`:

```
(?:This is a|\G(?!\A))\h+((?=.*so it is\.)string\d+)
```

- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match
- `(?!\A)` is negative lookahead to assert that we don't match `\G` at the line start
- `(?=.*so it is\.)` is positive lookahead to assert that we have `so it is.` ahead of current position in input

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MG8mJR/1)

**Code:**

```
$re = '/(?:This is a|\G(?!\A))\h+((?=.*so it is\.)string\d+)/m';
$str = 'This is a string1 string2 string3 string4 string5 string6 string7 so it is.';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches[1]);
```